# Excel - return minimum value in one list not present in another

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a formula that would return the minimum value in one list that does not exist in another list.

Unfortunately I cannot post a screenshot, so here is sample date:
Column A, Rows 1-10: 189, 208, 228, 231, 235, 252, 253, 264, 274, 278
Column B, Rows 1-10: 235, 253, 264, 252, 278, 286, 274, 310, 317, 330

I would like cell A11 to return the minimum value in the range B1:B10 that is not present in the range A1:A10. Since 235, 253, 264, 252, 278, and 274 appear in column A, the value in cell A11 would be 286. Thanks for your help.

Comment: is this in VB or do you want a excel cell formula?

Answer (score 3):

If your `B1:B10` doesn't contains empty cells, use this one:

```
=MIN(IF(ISNA(MATCH(B1:B10,A1:A10,0)),B1:B10))
```

otherwise:

```
=MIN(IF((B1:B10<>"")*ISNA(MATCH(B1:B10,A1:A10,0)),B1:B10))
```

for both formulas press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evauate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. The formula works great. Much Appreciated.